# ExtJS: show/hide events don't cascade down?

Tags: extjs

Is there a known limitation (or bug?) in ExtJS 3.2.x where events like show/hide fail to always be cascaded down a hierarchy of panels?

I have a panel that is nested inside a hierarchy of other panels. This panel's "show" event only fires the very first time it's shown. The "show" event in the "root" panel fires every time, however.

[This forum post](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?57454-DISCUSS-Cascade-events-to-subcomponents) seems to indicate that events are not cascaded in 3.x. Can someone confirm or offer more info?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Show/hide events are indeed not cascaded. The reason is that show/hide is actually just a dom manipulation and has nothing to do with the component hierarchy.

If a component contains sub components they are dom descendants of the containing component and thus also hidden if the containing components dom node is hidden. But this is just a side effect of the dom hierarchy of the components, not of the component hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks Chris. Do you know if there is some other event analogous to show/hide that *does* get cascaded? Wanting to know when a panel is shown (every time), even if it has several parents, seems like a not-too-uncommon need; I can't find anything like this in the docs or by trial-and-error, however.

Comment: Every `Ext.Component` has a `bubble()` method that calls an arbitrary function you pass to it on each component, up in the component hierarchy. this way you should be able to find if any parent component has `hidden = true` => http://dev.sencha.com/deploy/dev/docs/?class=Ext.Component

Answer (score 1):

You may be able to cascade using the `cascade` method, if the component you are working with supports it (`Ext.layout.Panel`s do). For example, if you had a panel, contained within a panel, and you wanted to hiden the child panel when the parent was hidden, you could try this:

```
validXTypes = ['panel'] //include any other valid types

parentPanel.cascade(function () {
    //if this component can be hidden...
    if (validXTypes.indexOf(this.xtype) != -1) {
        //...then hide it!
        this.hide();
    }
});
```